# Simple crypt for learning ruby?

Tags: ruby, cryptography

I want to write a program to take a users input, shift each character one to the right of it (a = b, b = c, c = d etc...). How would I do this without having the input spaced like this = h e l l o  w o r l d.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you get z->a also.  Like this:

```
"hallo world zzz".tr("a-z", "b-za")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to shift all characters in a word one position to the right, you can use the `rotate` method in the Array class and turn it back into a string:

```
irb(main):008:0> word = "helloworld"
=> "helloworld"
irb(main):009:0> array = []
=> []
irb(main):010:0> word.each_char { |c| array << c }
=> "helloworld"
irb(main):011:0> array
=> ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "w", "o", "r", "l", "d"]
irb(main):012:0> array = array.rotate(-1)
=> ["d", "h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "w", "o", "r", "l"]
irb(main):014:0> array.join('')
=> "dhelloworl"
```

Hope that helps... two years later!

Comment: Lol thanks! I don't even remember writing this question but I'm trying to learn ruby again, So I will for sure do this!

Answer (score 0):

For a binary string:

```
input = ...

encrypted =     input.bytes.map {|b| (b == 255 ? 0 : b+1).chr }.join
decrypted = encrypted.bytes.map {|b| (b == 0 ? 255 : b-1).chr }.join

decrypted == input   # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not writing you the solution, it's really easy.

You need to read about Ruby string manipulation.

http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html (look for `tr`)

and the last one is a good article about differences between 1.8.7 and 1.9.1

http://abhilekh.wordpress.com/2009/10/22/ruby-1-8-7-vs-ruby-1-9-1/

Comment: If you are interested in simple cryptography, have a look at RC4 which is simple to program and is a lot stronger than your Caesar cypher.